# There is an issue with my if-else statements where my variables are not getting initialized

Tags: java, if-statement, initialization

I am writing a simple program in Java that determines the numerical order of three users inputted integers values. For some reason, when I build the program, it says that my variables, min, mid, and max, have not been initialized. Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MinMidMax
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.print ("This program finds the minimum, maximum, and    middle number of three numbers that you input.");

    System.out.print ("\n\nEnter your first number: ");
    int num1 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print ("Enter your second number: ");
    int num2 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print ("Enter your third number: ");
    int num3 = scan.nextInt();

    int min, mid, max;

    if (num1<=num2 && num1<=num3)
    {min = num1;
        if (num2<=num3)
        {
            mid = num2;
            max = num3;
        }
        if (num3<=num2)
        {
            mid = num3;
            max = num2;
        }
    }
    if (num2<=num1 && num2<=num3)
    {min = num2;
        if (num1<=num3)
        {   mid = num1;
            max = num3;
        }
        if (num3<=num2)
        {
            mid = num3;
            max = num2;
        }
    }
    if (num3<=num1 && num3<=num2)
    {min = num3;
        if (num1<=num2)
        {   mid = num1;
            max = num2;
        }
        if (num2<=num1)
        {
            mid = num2;
            max = num1;
        }
    }

    System.out.print ("\nMinimum: " + min);
    System.out.print ("\nMiddle: " + mid);
    System.out.print ("\nMaximum: " + max);
}
}
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is with my if statements, but i'm not sure what it is. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The compiler is just telling you that there _might_ be cases where these variables aren't initialized correctly. The compiler doesn't do a "logical" check of your `if` statements.

Answer (score 3):

Even though one of the 3 outer `if` statements is guaranteed to be `true`, the compiler doesn't know this, so it thinks `min`, `max` and `mid` may not have been assigned values.

The solution is just to give them dummy values when you declare them:

```
int min = 0;
int max = 0;
int mid = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are absolutely sure that always ONE (no less and no more) condition is true write it that way:

```
if(condition1) {
    //code
} else if(condition2) {
    //code2
} else {
    //code3
}
```

You don't need to check if condition3 is true if both condition1 and condition2 are false. You could also use switch statement (and default action).By the way your code is to long and complicated for such a small task. Try just sort those 3 variables instead of comparing all possible pairs many times. Imagine that you have 100, not 3 numbers - would you still compare all possibilities? :)